# Sitecore: exclude template field from template section

Tags: templates, sitecore

I have a template (called Main news) that inherits a template section (called Image) with a number of fields in it. Now I want to use most of these fields on the Main news template, except for one. However, when I try to inherit the fields separately (as to not include the field I don't need), none of the fields appear on the Main news template.

Apparently, the entire Image template section is needed to use the fields on the Main news template. Is there a way to inherit from the Image template section, but exclude particular fields from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitecore, Templates inherit Templates only, you can't just inherit specific fields of a template, However, what you can do is break your Image template into 2 or more templates, where you can group the fields that should always be together, for example:

1. _Image_Group1

   - Field A
   - Field B
2. _Image_Group2

   - Field C

Now, Let say your Main template only needs Field A and Field B, So you just inherit from `_Image_Group1` template, If on another template you need also Field C, then you add `_Image_Group2` to base templates (eg, Image template )

So you end up with:

1. Image template inherit from `_Image_Group1` & `_Image_Group2`
2. Main template inherit from `_Image_Group1`

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to know if there was an easier option!